# Как найти максимальную последовательность обеих значений?

Tags: python

Задача:

У вас есть последовательность бросков монеты. Каждый бросок записан в массиве. Вам необходимо
вычислить самую длинную последовательность из орлов и самую длинную последовательность из решек

пример входных данных:
['орел', 'орел', 'решка', 'орел', 'решка', 'решка', 'решка', 'решка']

пример выходных:
Самая длинная последовательность решек: 4
Самая длинная последовательность орлов: 3

я нашел только 1 решение и то оно на javascript - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QxC__IU6jM

мой код:
он не полный

```
n = ['орел', 'орел', 'решка', 'решка', 'орел', 'решка', ]

countR = []
countO = []

for i in n:
    if i == 'орел':
      countO.append(1)
    elif i == 'решка':
      countR.append(1)
             print(len(countO), len(countR))
```

Comment: А надо на искать решение, а решать самостоятельно. хорошая задача для новичков, решайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если решать в лоб, то надо завести две переменные: `heads_ending_here` - число орлов подряд до этого места в списке и `max_heads_so_far` - максимальное число орлов подряд до сих пор.

Если встретился орёл, то `heads_ending_here` увеличивается на единицу, иначе сбрасывается в ноль.

Каждый раз когда `heads_ending_here` растёт надо обновить `max_heads_so_far`.

В начале цикла обе переменные нулевые. В конце в `max_heads_so_far` будет нужный вам ответ.

```
tosses = ['орел', 'орел', 'решка', 'орел', 'решка', 'решка', 'решка', 'решка']

max_heads_so_far = 0
heads_endging_here = 0

for t in tosses:
    if t == 'орел':
        heads_endging_here += 1
        if heads_endging_here > max_heads_so_far:
            max_heads_so_far = heads_endging_here 
    else:
        heads_endging_here = 0

print('орлы', max_heads_so_far)
```

Добавим решки:

```
tosses = ['орел', 'орел', 'решка', 'орел', 'решка', 'решка', 'решка', 'решка']

max_heads_so_far = 0
max_tails_so_far = 0
heads_endging_here = 0
tails_endging_here = 0

for t in tosses:
    if t == 'орел':
        heads_endging_here += 1
        if heads_endging_here > max_heads_so_far:
            max_heads_so_far = heads_endging_here 
        tails_endging_here = 0
    if t == 'решка':
        heads_endging_here = 0
        tails_endging_here += 1
        if tails_endging_here > max_tails_so_far:
            max_tails_so_far = tails_endging_here 

print('орлы', max_heads_so_far)
print('решки', max_tails_so_far)
```

Решения выше не используют возможности стандартной библиотеки Питона. А в ней есть [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) который хорошо подходит к задаче. `groupby` сам нарезает список на группы одинаковых элементов, нам нужно только посчитать длины групп и обновить максимумы:

```
import itertools

tosses = ['орел', 'орел', 'решка', 'орел', 'решка', 'решка', 'решка', 'решка']

max_heads_so_far = 0
max_tails_so_far = 0

for t, group in itertools.groupby(tosses):
    group_length = sum(1 for _ in group)
    if t == 'орел':
        if group_length > max_heads_so_far:
            max_heads_so_far = group_length 
    if t == 'решка':
        if group_length > max_tails_so_far:
            max_tails_so_far = group_length 

print('орлы', max_heads_so_far)
print('решки', max_tails_so_far)
```

Меня беспокоит в коде выше дублирование. Две переменные для максимумов обрабатываются совершенно одинаково. Исправим это - заведем словарь, который хранит текущие максимумы. Вот так:

```
import itertools

tosses = ['орел', 'орел', 'решка', 'орел', 'решка', 'решка', 'решка', 'решка']

maxima_so_far = {'орел': 0, 'решка': 0}

for t, group in itertools.groupby(tosses):
    group_length = sum(1 for _ in group)
    if group_length > maxima_so_far[t]:
        maxima_so_far[t] = group_length

for t, m in maxima_so_far.items():
    print(t, m)
```

Последний штрих - избавимся от фиксированной структуры словаря. Пусть записи добавляются только при необходимости. Вместо обращения `dict[key]` используем `dict.get(key, 0)`. Если ключа в словаре ещё нет, вернётся ноль. То что нужно. Теперь код сможет обрабатывать списки с любыми значениями:

```
import itertools

tosses = ['орел', 'орел', 'решка', 'орел', 'решка', 'решка', 'решка', 'решка']

maxima_so_far = {}

for t, group in itertools.groupby(tosses):
    group_length = sum(1 for _ in group)
    if group_length > maxima_so_far.get(t, 0):
        maxima_so_far[t] = group_length

for t, m in maxima_so_far.items():
    print(t, m)
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, за 3 код. Я понял задачу и понял работу itertools

Answer (score 4):

можно решить в лоб, как тестовая задача - очень неплохая

в вашем случае вы приводите неправильный код - он подсчитывает только общее кол-во орлов и решек, вам же нужно определять, что последовательность только орлов закончена и считать результат, т.е. в вашем случае код надо было бы дополнить:

```
countR = []
countO = []

for i in n:
    if i == 'орел':
      # считаем длину countR И если она больше максимальной - запоминаем
      # сбрасываем массив countR в 0
      countO.append(1)
    elif i == 'решка':
      # считаем длину countL И если она больше максимальной - запоминаем
      # сбрасываем массив countL в 0
      countR.append(1)
```

но тут вопрос такой - а зачем вам тогда вообще массивы, если вы можете считать кол-во через переменную?

а можно мыслить чуть нестандартно и тогда можно делать однострочные развраты

```
n = ['орел', 'орел', 'решка', 'решка', 'орел', 'решка', ]

print(max(map(len, ''.join(map(lambda key: {'орел': '*', 'решка': '+'}.get(key, '*'), n)).split('*'))))
```

одна строчка для орлов и решек:

```
res = max(map(len, ''.join(map(lambda key: {'орел': '*', 'решка': '+'}.get(key, '*'), n)).split('*'))), max(map(len, ''.join(map(lambda key: {'орел': '*', 'решка': '+'}.get(key, '+'), n)).split('+')))
```

ну или если поджать:

```
res = [max(map(len, ''.join(map(lambda key: {'орел': '*', 'решка': '+'}.get(key, i), n)).split(i))) for i in ('*', '+')]
```

Comment: можно немного по понятнее этот код сделать, мне как для новичка это слишком сложно выглядит, и если можно можете все это через if else сделать, как на ютубе

Comment: для новичка я написал код выше - просто в комментариях вам надо вставить свой код

второй же код основан на том, что мы слова заменяем на символы, разбиваем последовательность через другие символы и считаем длину полученных строк, максимальная длина строки и показывает сколько орлов или решек у вас максимально последовательно

Comment: похоже что однострочный вариант выводит только максимальную длину последовательности решек (по условию нужно найти максимальную длину обеих последовательностей)

Comment: конечно - для орлов сделайте разбиение по `+`: `print(max(map(len, ''.join(map(lambda key: {'орел': '*', 'решка': '+'}.get(key, '+'), n)).split('+'))))`

Comment: Даёшь однострочку сразу для орлов и решек!

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, а держите :) даже через `for` :)

Comment: `res = [max(sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(n) if k == t) for t in set(n)]`.
Такое принимается?

Comment: ну библиотеку использовать еще :) но почему и нет

Comment: Без библиотеки: `res = [max(map(len, ''.join('.' if v == t else ' ' for v in n).split())) for t in set(n)]`.

Answer (score 0):

добавлю в копилку еще одно решение (бонусом выводит еще и длину минимальной последовательности):

```
n = ['орел', 'орел', 'орел', 'решка', 'решка', 'орел', 'решка', 'решка', 'решка']
d = {'орел':[0], 'решка':[0]}
s = []

for i in n + ['end']:
    if s and i not in s:
        d[s[0]].append(len(s))
        s.clear()
    s.append(i)

print(f'MAX: орел {max(d["орел"])}, решка {max(d["решка"])}')
print(f'MIN: орел {min(d["орел"])}, решка {min(d["решка"])}')
```

результат:

```
MAX: орел 3, решка 3
MIN: орел 1, решка 2
```

код работает достаточно просто:

Проходим циклом по списку бросков `n`, записываем в список `s` какая сторона монеты выпала до тех пор пока не выпадет противоположная сторона. Когда выпадает другая сторона, записываем в соответствующий список словаря `d` длину списка `s` и очищаем список `s`. Итого, в словаре `d` имеем списки длин всех последовательностей орлов и решек. Стандартной функцией `max` находим длины наибольших (заодно можем и наименьших).

Чтобы в цикле не потерялась последняя последовательность бросков, к списку `n` добавлено значение 'end'.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy так не будет работать, в начале  `s`  пустой список и  `s[0]`  вызовет ошибку